Consequence of Cauchy's theorem
Let $f,g$ be two holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ and suppose that $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)\ dz=\int_\gamma g(z)\ dz$$ for every $\gamma$ closed curve. Then, $f=g$.
This is a prove/disprove exercise that my teacher left me to think about.
I think it's false because that integrals are equal for every $f,g$ holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Indeed, that integrals are both zero (Cauchy's theorem) but $f$ can be different from $g$.
Is this a correct argument? How can I formalize it a little better? Is there an easy example?

holomorphic

The easiest example is probably $f=0$ and $g=1$, where this follows from Green's theorem.

You're completely correct.
For instance let $f(z)=z$ and $g(z)=z^2.$  (Any two unequal entire functions will do.)
And only one counterexample is necessary to disprove the claim.
Note $f\ne g$ since for instance $f(2)\ne g(2).$
